# /usr/sbin/sendmail: Permission denied

Tags: fedora, permissions, selinux, sendmail

I am trying to setup the mail on my fedora 20. Every time I try to fire a test mail it tells me the permission is denied on `/usr/sbin/sendmail`.

I checked the permissions and this is the output:

```
[root@localhost uone]# ls -ld /usr/sbin/sendmail
drwxr-sr-x. 2 uone uone 4096 Jun 14 17:42 /usr/sbin/sendmail
```

when I check the logs in `/var/logs/mail`, I get this

```
[root@localhost uone]# ls /var/log/maillog
/var/log/maillog
```

and

```
[root@localhost home]# cat /var/log/maillog
[root@localhost home]#
```

Running `ls -l` gives me this

```
[root@localhost home]# ls -l /var/log/maillog
-rw-------. 1 root root 0 Jul 6 11:27 /var/log/maillog
```

Doing a `ls -l` on sendmail directory gives me this

```
[root@localhost sbin]# ls -l | grep sendmail
drwxr-sr-x. 2 uone uone 4096 Jun 14 17:42 sendmail lrwxrwxrwx. 1 root root 15 Jul 12 19:04 sendmail.ssmtp -> /usr/sbin/ssmtp
```

**I have two questions:**

1. Am I missing something in setting up the "mail"? Is there anything else I need to do before I can try sending a mail?
2. How can I get the logs to find out exactly what's happening?

Comment: I would be more useful to actually _read_ the logfile rather than display its path. Try `cat /var/log/maillog`.

Comment: Thanks for replying. I did the ls to see if it has anything. I just did a cat on the path; Here is the output 

[root@localhost home]# cat /var/log/maillog
[root@localhost home]#

Comment: /usr/sbin/sendmail is a directory?? What does `ls -l /usr/sbin/sendmail` show? What OS are you using?

Comment: I am running fedora 20 on vmware 8. Running ls -l gives me this "[root@localhost home]# ls -l /var/log/maillog
-rw-------. 1 root root 0 Jul  6 11:27 /var/log/maillog
"

Doing a ls -l on sendmail directory gives me this
  [root@localhost sbin]# ls -l | grep sendmail
drwxr-sr-x. 2 uone uone    4096 Jun 14 17:42 sendmail
lrwxrwxrwx. 1 root root      15 Jul 12 19:04 sendmail.ssmtp -> /usr/sbin/ssmtp

Comment: Do you have a MTA (like postfix/sendmail/exim) installed ?
I'm using postfix on F20 and my `/usr/sbin/sendmail` is actually a link to `/usr/sbin/sendmail.postfix`.

Comment: Please [edit] your question to add extra information, it is hard to read and easy to miss in the comments.

Comment: @Rabin I changed your answer to a comment since it was not really offering a solution to the OP.

Comment: This might sound stupid but do i need to configure "mail" for any info like protocol selection,incoming/outgoing addresses before i can try sending a mail? 

I am using this instance for sometime now and never thought of sending a mail via terminal. So this is the first time i am trying to send the mail..If i need to install some plugin/package via yum or need to configure the mail parameters please let me know..

Comment: It looks like a misinstalled ssmtp package. Try `rpm -v -V ssmtp` and see if there are any errors. The fix may be as simple as removing that /usr/sbin/sendmail directory and replacing it with a symlink. You do have to do some configuration of ssmtp if you have anything more involved than a network with a mail hub named 'mail.yourdomain'.

Comment: Sure Mark! I am at work right now..will do this once i reach home and let you know how it works..

Comment: The `.` after the permissions in the `ls` output means that there's an SELinux context. What does `ls -Z /usr/sbin/sendmail` say? Does `restorecon -v /usr/sbin/sendmail` help? What MTA did you install (what package provides `/usr/sbin/sendmail`)? What else did you do to “setup the mail”?

Comment: @Mark Interestingly i saw missing files in rpm -v -V ssmtp. 

[uone@localhost mail]$ rpm -v -V ssmtp
.........    /etc/ssmtp
missing   c /etc/ssmtp/revaliases (Permission denied)
missing   c /etc/ssmtp/ssmtp.conf (Permission denied)

Doing a ls -l on it gives me "[uone@localhost etc]$ ls -l ssmtp/
ls: cannot open directory ssmtp/: Permission denied
[uone@localhost etc]$ sudo ls -l ssmtp/
total 8
-rw-r--r--. 1 root root  200 Apr 16  2001 revaliases
-rwxr-s---. 1 root mail 1483 Jan 19 00:49 ssmtp.conf"

I have not done any other config on mail to answer the 2nd part. Any suggestions?

Comment: @Giles ls -Z gives me no output and so does the restorecon. I have not installed any MTA separately. Nothing else did to setup the mail. Do i need to install any other package along with mail to support sending mails?

Comment: Please run `rpm -v -V ssmtp` as root.

Comment: @MarkPlotnick There you go. Seems like its a different output this time 
[root@localhost Scripts]# rpm -v -V ssmtp
.........    /etc/ssmtp
.........  c /etc/ssmtp/revaliases
.........  c /etc/ssmtp/ssmtp.conf
.........    /usr/bin/mailq.ssmtp
.........    /usr/bin/newaliases.ssmtp
.........    /usr/sbin/sendmail.ssmtp
.........    /usr/sbin/ssmtp
.........    /usr/share/doc/ssmtp

Comment: It looks like /usr/sbin/sendmail got created as a directory by mistake. As root, do `rmdir /usr/sbin/sendmail` and `yum reinstall ssmtp`. This will, among other things, reinstall the files in /etc/ssmtp, so if you've edited them and want the changes preserved, copy them somewhere first.

Comment: @MarkPlotnick i have removed the dir and reinstalled the ssmtp package. Can you suggest what changes i do in /etc/ssmtp/ssmtp.conf and /etc/ssmtp/revaliases file. I tried using the mail hub information from gmail and it doesnt seem to like it. PS This is first time i edited the above said files..

Comment: Look at https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/SSMTP for a suggested configuration.

Comment: going through it..

Comment: I installed ssmtp on Fedora 20 and it resulted in /usr/sbin/sendmail being a symlink to /etc/alternatives/mta, which is a symlink to /usr/sbin/sendmail.ssmtp . Is that what you see now?

Comment: @Mark Seems like mine is pointing to postfix (I installed postfix in hope of sending a mail anyway)`[uone@localhost ~]$ ls -l /usr/sbin/sendmail
lrwxrwxrwx. 1 root root 21 Jul 20 13:56 /usr/sbin/sendmail -> /etc/alternatives/mta
[uone@localhost ~]$ ls -l /etc/alternatives/mta
lrwxrwxrwx. 1 root root 26 Jul 20 13:56 /etc/alternatives/mta -> /usr/sbin/sendmail.postfix
[uone@localhost ~]$ 
`

Answer (score 3):

Your permissions issue is not a file permissions issue but SELinux disallowing the sendmail executable from accessing files on the filesystem in a specific location. Your best friend for dealing with these is to use the SELinux troubleshooter GUI.

```
$ sealert -b
```

[image: ss#1]

You'll then want to follow the advice to add the necessary contexts to your filesystem to appease SELinux.

[image: ss #2]

**NOTE:** In the above example I've selected the 2nd option and will run the commands `semanage` and `restorecon` as described to fix my issue here. You'll need to do the same for your `sendmail` issue.

#### Part of Fedora?

Yes SELinux, and therefore the tools used to troubleshoot are part of all the Red Hat distros. Whenever I cannot locate the name of a package a given executable is a member of I turn to the command `repoquery`.

```
$ repoquery -qf */sealert
setroubleshoot-server-0:3.2.17-1.fc20.x86_64
setroubleshoot-server-0:3.2.14-2.fc20.x86_64
```

#### Issues running as a GUI

If you're running into problems running `sealert` as a GUI you can drop back to running it via a terminal like so:

```
$ sudo sealert -a /var/log/audit/audit.log | less
```

You'll then have to look through the output for your particular issue and use the suggested commands to fix your SELinux issues.  You're looking for the lines that say something along these lines:

> *****  Plugin openvpn (47.5 confidence) suggests   ***************************

The ones with the higher "confidence" values are the actions you'll likely want to take. The commands to "fix" the SELinux issues follow after these lines, for example:

```
$ sudo semanage fcontext -a -t home_cert_t /home/slm/somedom.com.ca.crt
$ sudo restorecon -R -v /home/slm/somedom.com.ca.crt
```

#### References

- [5. Troubleshooting SELinux](http://wiki.centos.org/HowTos/SELinux)
- [SELinux Howto](http://wiki.centos.org/HowTos/SELinux)

Comment: Is sealert available for fedora? i doubt it. Could not find it via yum..

Comment: @Atul - yes it is. I got those screenshots from running it on Fedora 20. It's in this pkg: setroubleshoot-server.

Comment: @Atul - see updates.

Comment: Bad luck! i tried launching the program and it tells me it can not attach to the desktop process. _[root@localhost uone]# sealert 
could not attach to desktop process_. I tried looking up the sealert via repoquery and it does nothing on the other hand it tells me setroubleshooter is installed fine. Any other way we can work on the SE part? Let me know if you need any logs?

Comment: @Atul - see updates.

Comment: Amazingly the SE troubleshooter ran (i guess re installing the package and reboot did the trick). I got a screen which stays there for a while. Is this normal? PS Click on the dropbox link for image, i couldnt add to comment. https://www.dropbox.com/s/5ppr9yw9hmnwiqs/SE%20Troubleshooter.JPG

Comment: @Atul - Try setting it so that you receive alerts.

Comment: Okay will do that and let you know...

Comment: Nope! Doesn't work for me Slm.

Comment: @Atul - command line mode produced nothing from sealert?

Comment: It shows nothing but blank window..

Comment: @Atul - is the log file: `var/log/audit/audit.log` empty? All the "issues" that SELinux encounters are kept there.

Comment: At work Slm. Will check this first thing in morning and reply back to you. Thank you!

Comment: Slm i just checked the file and seems like it has content. What should i be looking for ? Grep "mail" may be ?

Comment: @Atul - there should be multiple versions of that file, it get's rotated by `logrotate`. I'm wondering if your sendmail msgs are in an old log file? Look in `/var/log/audit`, you need to be root to see this dir or use `sudo`. You can use `sealert -a /var/log/audit/audit.log.1` for example.

Comment: sorry about being late in reply. I did a sealert -a on the file and found this. I dont think i found anything relevant but i would really want you to check and share your inputs. Please use this link to see the log data(The data exceeds the char limit) [link] https://www.dropbox.com/s/thta7v6mkdlou33/Sealert%20audit%20log.txt [link]

Comment: @Atul - yeah this isn't pertaining to the sendmail issue you've been debugging. You'd need to retrigger the sendmail issue to get it to show up in the latest logs.

Comment: Okay.I will retry the mail sending exercise again and try to capture the logs...

Comment: I tried sending the mail again and found that mail is being denied by google for some reason. Also the default MTA seems to be postfix here..Check out the new sealert and mail log..[link]https://www.dropbox.com/s/jztwu2zebqdo4ab/Sealert%2029%20july.rar [link]