# SELinux and OpenVPN?

Tags: openvpn, selinux

Having Fedora 20 64-bit installed, I have this old problem of conflicting OpenVPN and SELinux. Obviously SELinux prevents `openvpn` from launching.

The OpenVPN has been set through ***Network Connection*** and I have three files:

- user certificate as: `cer.pem`
- CA certificate as: `ca.pem`
- Private key as: `key.pem`

Some solutions say that I should move certificate files in to `~/.cert` and then run:

```
$ sudo restorecon -R -v ~/.cert
```

And then SELinux will allow the access to the certificates.

BUT, before I launch `openvpn`, I had saved these certificates in Documents/certificates folder. Of course when I execute:

```
$ mv ~/Documents/certificates/cer.pem ~/.cert
```

The file will be moved to `~/.cert` and in Network Connections there would be no certificates.

I've tried to use `cp` instead of `mv` but that did not help and still I have this old problem of conflict.

Answer (score 6):

SELinux is disallowing the `openvpn` executable from accessing files on the filesystem in a specific location. Your best friend for dealing with these is to use the SELinux troubleshooter GUI.

```
$ sealert -b
```

[image: ss#1]

You'll then want to follow the advice to add the necessary contexts to your filesystem to appease SELinux.

[image: ss #2]

**NOTE:** In the above example I've selected the 2nd option and will run the commands `semanage` and `restorecon` as described to fix my issue here. You'll need to do the same for your `openvpn` issue. It should be identical to what I'm showing in the screenshots.

To fix the issue I ran these commands:

```
$ sudo semanage fcontext -a -t home_cert_t /home/slm/somedom.com.ca.crt
$ sudo restorecon -R -v /home/slm/somedom.com.ca.crt
```

#### References

- [/usr/sbin/sendmail: Permission denied](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/145051/usr-sbin-sendmail-permission-denied/)
- [5. Troubleshooting SELinux](http://wiki.centos.org/HowTos/SELinux)
- [SELinux Howto](http://wiki.centos.org/HowTos/SELinux)